# Distinguish between two vocals by their timbre

Tags: audio, frequency-spectrum, music

Right now I'm working on a signal processing project, I'm not quite to the point where I'm implementing the DSP algorithms yet (still working on the low level hardware) although I'd like to get an idea of what I can do.

I'd say the goal at best is to be able to distinguish between the [two vocal types in this song](https://youtu.be/tu2mVP6xee0?t=2m33s).  Basically at that point of the song, you can hear the main singers vocals and then a really sporadic background vocal.  The best case scenario would be to separate those two although I'm not quite sure how.  At this point I'll be doing a fast hartley transform implementation and a periodogram implementation, are there any other algorithms I could implement to achieve this goal of distinguishing between the to vocals?

Comment: I'd suggest you get the algorithm nailed down first, else you may end up building hardware that doesn't have enough oomph to carry out the needed algorithm.

Comment: @JRE I'm pretty sure the hardware is capable, possibly overkill, for the appplication, but if not, there are options without changing the hardware.  I'm more so just curious about what I could do on the dsp side of things to accomplish the goal